# Assigning type / creating struct via switch statement

Tags: go

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to either create a struct in a switch statement or assign a type to it in a switch statement.
Here's some non-working code illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```
var result

switch structPickingString {
case "struct1":
    result = new(struct1)
case "struct2":
    result = new(struct2)
}

//unmarshall some json into the appropriate struct type
if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
//print out that json with a function specific to that type of struct
result.Print()
```

I *think* something involving an empty `interface{}` might be related to solving this issue but unfortunately I'm still a bit ignorant with golang and I'm not seeing how to make it work.

Here's a link to a slightly modified version of the code for more context: https://play.golang.org/p/Rb1oaMuvmU2

The issue is not defining the print function, it's assigning a specific type of struct to the `result` variable based on using the individual `Print` function that the struct implements.

Let me know if there's any more info I could provide.

Comment: what is the error you are facing ?

Comment: Do not take the address of `result` in call to Decode.  Also, declare `result` as type `interface{}`.

Comment: How would `.Decode` unmarshall anything to an `interface{}`?

Comment: @zerkms that's literally the type signature of it: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode

Comment: @dave then it uses reflection to unmarshall fields. Given the original type is `interface{}` it would never be populated.

Comment: @Apolozeus If I were to define the variable `result` in each case statement, it would go out of scope before I could use it after the switch block. I don't know how to declare it in a *generic* way (because I won't know what type it needs to be until the switch statement is evaluated) before the switch statement so that it does not go out of scope.

Comment: @zerkms The interface value has type `*struct1` or `*struct2`. The decoder uses reflection to decode JSON to structs.

Comment: @ThunderCat oh gosh, I need glasses, sorry (I also mentioned reflections above, those assignments for some reason got into my blind spot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are calling `.Print`, you need to use an interface which has that method.  I think you are looking for something like

```
type Printer interface {
    Print()
}

func (s *struct1) Print() {
  // ...
}

func (s *struct2) Print() {
  // ...
}
var result Printer
switch structPickingString {
case "struct1":
    result = new(struct1)
case "struct2":
    result = new(struct2)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/W9r6UfeQSCz

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think I may have been a little unclear in my post. I already have the printing interface coded and working. (Each struct implements it.) My issue is making `result` an instance of either `struct1` or `struct2` depending on the value of the `structPickingString`

Comment: but... why?  you have it as an instance of the interface, do you need access to other methods that aren't part of the interface?

Comment: I'm sorry, upon rereading your post and looking at what some other people posted, your answer is the correct one. The way you used the Printer interface confused me at first making me think you thought my issue was trying to implement the printing function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You needs match "generical interface" with structs. See this:

```
//my struct1
type MyStruct1 struct {
    ID int
}

//my struct2
type MyStruct2 struct {
    ID int
}

//my interface
type MyStructGenerical interface {
    Print()
}

//method (match with MyStructGenerical)
func (m1 MyStruct1) Print() {
    println(m1.ID)
}

//method (match with MyStructGenerical)
func (m2 MyStruct2) Print() {
    println(m2.ID)
}
```

In this way you can does assertions between structs and generical interface. See this:

```
//here result is an generical interface
var result MyStructGenerical = nil

//checkin
switch structPickingString {
case "struct1":
    tmp := new(MyStruct1)
    result = tmp
case "struct2":
    tmp := new(MyStruct2)
    result = tmp
}
```

The result is:

```
//unmarshall some json into the appropriate struct type
if err := json.NewDecoder(body()).Decode(&result); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

//print out that json with a function specific to that type of struct
tmp := result.(*MyStruct1)
tmp.Print()
// or
result.Print()
```

Run in: https://play.golang.org/p/nHrJnImsqNN

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use an interface like

```
type ResultIface interface {
     Print()
}
```

Then you can do

```
 var result ResultIface

 switch structPickingString {
 case "struct1":
     result = new(struct1)
 case "struct2":
     result = new(struct2)
}
```

As long as your struct1 and struct2 fulfills the ResultIface by having a Print function it will print